# Multiple logitech keyboards with different keymaps?

Tags: keyboard, usb, text-input

I have this at work -- http://www.logitech.com/en-us/product/wireless-solar-keyboard-k750-mac

and this at home -- http://www.logitech.com/en-us/product/k750-keyboard?crid=26&section=features

Every time I switch between the two work-zones I have to remap my keyboards via Settings > Keyboard > Modifier Keys (basically I have to switch the windows and alt keys on the windows one)

Is there a way to avoid this annoyance, or at least reduce it to a simple click switch?

It's especially difficult I think because of the fact that they use the same type of wireless USB receiver.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [KeyRemap4MacBook](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en) to [add settings for specific devices](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml-devicedef.html.en). EventViewer.app shows the vendor and product IDs.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <devicevendordef>
    <vendorname>HEWLETT_PACKARD</vendorname>
    <vendorid>0x03f0</vendorid>
  </devicevendordef>
  <deviceproductdef>
    <productname>MY_HP_KEYBOARD</productname>
    <productid>0x0224</productid>
  </deviceproductdef>
  <item>
    <name>test</name>
    <identifier>private.test</identifier>
    <device_only>DeviceVendor::HEWLETT_PACKARD, DeviceProduct::MY_HP_KEYBOARD</device_only>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::OPTION_L, KeyCode::COMMAND_L</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::OPTION_R, KeyCode::COMMAND_R</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::COMMAND_L, KeyCode::OPTION_L</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::COMMAND_R, KeyCode::OPTION_R</autogen>
  </item>
</root>
```

See the source for the [key code values](https://github.com/tekezo/KeyRemap4MacBook/blob/master/src/bridge/generator/keycode/data/KeyCode.data) and [predefined settings](http://raw.github.com/tekezo/KeyRemap4MacBook/master/Tests/lib/string/data/checkbox.xml).